# Program runs in eclipse, but not in .jar form

Tags: eclipse, jar, program-entry-point

I ran it in cmd and it said no main manifest attribute in, JGame2.jar

how do i show it where the main is?? it works fine in eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For

```
java -jar x.jar
```

to work, the jar file must contain a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file, and this file must contain an entry for the main class. You can add a manifest in Eclipse. Note that any dependencies must also be accounted for, either by:

- a class path in the manifest
- -cp on the command line
- use of some tool to combine to one jar

Eclipse is just an IDE, you might consider learning to use an actual build tool such as Maven or Gradle or Ant to allow you to repeatably build usable results.